# Connecting to oracle database via Oracle wallet not working in go application

Tags: oracle, go

I have requirement to connect to oracle database via Oracle wallet in go application.
I referred: [pure-standalone.go](https://github.com/lucasjellema/go-oracle-database/blob/main/pure-standalone.go)

Below is code snippet from my application:

```
connectionUrl := go_ora.BuildUrl(Host, 1522, "db_service", "user", "pwd", nil)
connectionUrl += "?TRACE FILE=trace.log&SSL=enable&SSL Verify=false&WALLET=" + url.QueryEscape(walletpathStr)
conn, err := sql.Open("oracle", connectionUrl)
err = conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't establish connection: ", err)
    }
```

It didn't connect and I got: `Can't establish connection: EOF`

However i'am able to connect to my database with the same oracle wallet via sqlplus/sqldeveloper with the same user (I have set TNS_ADMIN=<wallet_dir> as env variable)

Then I tried to connect it using godror following: [with-oracleinstant-client.go](https://github.com/lucasjellema/go-oracle-database/blob/main/with-oracleinstant-client.go)

```
conn, err := sql.Open("godror", fmt.Sprintf(`user="%s" password="%s"
        connectString="tcps://%s:%s/%s?wallet_location=%s"
           `, "user", "pwd", "host", "1522", "service_name", "wallet_dir"))
```

This time I got: `godror: dpoPool_create user=ADMIN extAuth=0: ORA-28864: SSL connection closed gracefully`

I further deep dived into this error, but could not find anything applicable, nor where the problem is. Any help is appreciated